# Heat equation with function squared.

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

Can I seek some help on transforming the following heat equation
$$0 = \frac{\partial X(x,y)}{\partial x} + \frac{X^2(x,y)}{2k} + \frac{\sigma^2}{4 x^2} \frac{\partial^2 X(x,y)}{\partial y^2}$$

into a homogenous heat equation? The main problem I am stuck with is getting rid of the $\frac{X^2(x,y)}{2k}$ term.

I would know how to proceed from a heat equation with varying diffusion coefficient of the form $$0 = \frac{\partial U(s,y)}{\partial s} + \frac{\sigma^2}{4s^2} \frac{\partial^2 U(s,y)}{\partial y^2}$$

Thanks. The nature of this PDE arises from a project I’ve been working on.

Comment: Why should this be possible? Or is this the question?

Comment: Hmm, is a transformation possible? I assumed it was. And if it is, what would be the approach?

Comment: This is why I asked. If this was a problem from a book or something then you would *know* its possible, but if this is just some random equation you came up with then its very likely not possible. This is useful information (the context for the equation) to add to the question.

Comment: I see, thanks anyway. I managed to solve it, albeit as you mentioned, I left out details that were important for the context